# Having a Run-on Sentence Inside of Quotation Marks

Tags: quotations, run-on-sentence

I have a sentence that says this, "'They probably want us, let’s get out of here,' Jake said to Adam."

In a situation like this, is using correct grammar necessary? Do I have to say, "'They probably want us; let's get out of here,' Jake said to Adam.", or can I leave it as it was stated above?

Comment: I'm confused.  What do you perceive as the significant difference between the two, and why would you not prefer "correct grammar"?

Comment: The significant difference is that the first sentence is a run-on because it has a comma splice, while the second sentence is complete because it uses a semicolon. I 'would not prefer' correct grammar in this situation because I already turned the assignment in and was docked points for this. I was wondering if I really should have been, and if usage was at least acceptable in this situation.

Comment: Claiming a "comma splice" makes the sentence "run-on" when the semicolon does not is a bit P-ist, but it's the sort of pedanticism which is to be expected from some educators.  It's a silly technicality, but not worth arguing about (unless it makes the difference between passing and failing).

Comment: And if it does make a difference between a letter grade, then what would you say, because the semester is ending soon.

Comment: The thing is, unless you can get an authority like Strunk and White to back you up, you're not apt to change the instructor's mind.

Comment: (If the text you were quoting was from another printed text, then one might argue that it's more important to quote precisely than to correct any punctuation "errors" in the original author's work.  But when you're quoting, in essence, spoken language then there is no punctuation present in the original other than the pauses that one might hear, and one should generally strive to adhere to some "standard" of punctuation.  What "standard" is up to you ... and your instructor.)

Comment: An earlier [question and answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280898/comma-splices-in-dialogue) at ELU may be helpful to you if you want to argue the point. The gist is that comma splices in dialog are frequently excepted from the usual punctuation rules by publishers. As one answer points out, there is no punctuation in spoken dialog. Another answer addresses the question from the standpoint of a proofreader and copyeditor of novels.

Comment: If one punctuation mark is going to cost you a letter grade, then I think your professor needs to get a better rubric. :-) That said, following the advice that @HotLicks gave, let's assume this quotation was verbal and not written, so you have the liberty to punctuate it as you wish. Is there any need to keep that first part all part of one sentence? How about: _“‘They probably want us! Let’s get out of here,’ Jake said to Adam.”_

Answer (score -2):

Yes. You have two main clauses separated by a comma. Pop in a the word "so" and all is fine:

"They probably want us, **so** let’s get out of here," Jake said to Adam.

Comment: I think the issue here is that the first part of the sentence is a quotation. Thus, we can't "pop in a word" to make everything fine. (If Jake didn't say "so," then it shouldn't be added to the quote, hence the O.P.'s dilemma.)