# Can a non-finite clause come after semicolon?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, subordinate-clauses, nonfinite-verbs

> Every morning the princess wakes up and kisses the frog; hoping to see it turn into a prince.

Is the above construction wrong?

From *Of Mice and Men,* by John Steinbeck:

> His huge companion dropped his blankets and flung himself down and drank from the surface of the green pool; drank with long gulps, snorting into the water like a horse.

Comment: The semi-colon should be replaced by a comma there.

Comment: Is this within the purview of the site? I ask less to close and more to know for myself. I believe punctuation is here considered style rather than grammar. Yes?

Comment: One can argue that *he drank* is ellided from the second clause, so it could be considered correct. Even if someone rejected this explanation, punctuation is often times a matter of style, and punctuation usage, as does style, comes and goes.

Comment: @Unrelated I was randomly reading some Q & A's on ELU when I stumbled upon this interesting comment : 'In summary, don't look to novels to follow grammar and punctuation rules precisely; the priority in popular literature is more on style than perfection.' So I think yes? [Link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280898/comma-splices-in-dialogue)

Comment: Are artists bound to "rules"? Sculptors? Composers? If not, then why writers?

Answer (score 1):

A semicolon is most commonly used to link (in a single sentence) two independent clauses that are closely related in thought.
e.g: Some people write with a word processor; others write with a pen or pencil.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a non-finite clause can follow a semicolon.  A semicolon is used to separate independent clauses, each of which could stand alone. The example of the question,

> Every morning the princess wakes up and kisses the frog, hoping to see it turn into a prince.

requires a comma, since it has just one independent clause.  But we could have instead an expression where the dependent clause is part of a following independent clause:

> Every morning the princess wakes up and kisses the frog; hoping to see it turn into a prince, she tilts her head to receive a return of her kiss.